# meteor angular "HTML template does not exists!"

Tags: angular-meteor

I'm relatively new to meteor, but have already some experience in AngularJS. 
Now I have installed with the command `npm install -g generator-angular-meteor` the "angular-meteor-generator".
It works so far everything, but once the app starts, I get the error message

```
client/components/toolbar/toolbar.view.ng.html - HTML template does not exists!
```

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

and my toolbar-directive:

```
'use strict'
angular.module('smashoArtikelVerwaltungApp')
.directive('toolbar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: 'client/components/toolbar/toolbar.view.ng.html',
    replace: true
  };
});
```

I have not made any changes of the generated code. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a long time to fix the problem, I came up with the following solution:
Downgrade the meteror version :

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sed 's/1.4.0.1/1.3.3.1/' | sh
```

Simple, fast, but not elegant.